# Read pub/sub message in DAG

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-composer

I'm new to GCP.
I have created a Pub/Sub Topic and a Cloud Function.
1.When a Message is Published to Topic the Cloud function is Executed and it invokes a DAG in Cloud Composer.

I want to read the published message in the DAG file.
how to do that?

Comment: Can you check this answer, as, from my point of view, it may help: [Trigger Cloud Composer DAG with a Pub/Sub message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58575463/6073141)

Comment: @al-dann am able to trigger the DAG. I facing an issue to pull pub/sub message into a DAG as a variable.

Comment: I meant this link from the answer I mentioned above: https://incubator-airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/operator/google/cloud/pubsub.html#pulling-messages-from-a-pubsub-subscription

Comment: @al-dann I used another approach. 1) I have created a table in Bigquery. 2). I used Bigquery Client in cloud function which adds records to the Bq table and then it triggers the DAG. 3) In that I used a BigQueryHook to read data from Bq.

Comment: @al-dann Here the Link of i refered for bigQuery Hook                                        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53565834/fetch-results-from-bigqueryoperator-in-airflow